# regex for a pattern at end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string which looks like:

```
hello/world/1.9.2-some-text
hello/world/2.0.2-some-text
hello/world/2.11.0
```

Through regex I want to get the string after last '/' and until end of line i.e. in above examples output should be 1.9.2-some-text, 2.0.2-some-text, 2.11.0

I tried this -  `^(.+)\/(.+)$` which returns me an array of which first object is "`hello/world`" and 2nd object is "`1.9.2-some-text`"

Is there a way to just get "1.9.2-some-text" as the output?

Comment: Are these file paths? If so, treat them as such and use the built-in methods in the File class, like [`basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-basename), which is made for this purpose, and is aware of the path delimiters for the OS the code is running on. The [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-split) method might be useful to you also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a negative [character class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) (`[^…]`) like this:

```
[^\/]+$
```

This will match one or more of any character other than `/` followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Good one!  Implementation: `str.lines.map { |l| l[/[^\/]+$/] }
=> ["1.9.2-some-text\n", "2.0.2-some-text\n", "2.11.0"]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negated match here.

```
'hello/world/1.9.2-some-text'.match(Regexp.new('[^/]+$'))
# => "1.9.2-some-text"
```

Meaning any character except: `/` (**1** or more times) followed by the end of the string.

Although, the simplest way would be to split the string.

```
'hello/world/1.9.2-some-text'.split('/').last
# => "1.9.2-some-text"
```

OR

```
'hello/world/1.9.2-some-text'.split('/')[-1]
# => "1.9.2-some-text"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to use a regex, the ordinary way of doing such thing is:

```
File.basename("hello/world/1.9.2-some-text")
#=> "1.9.2-some-text"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
s = 'hello/world/1.9.2-some-text
hello/world/2.0.2-some-text
hello/world/2.11.0'

s.lines.map { |l| l[/.*\/(.*)/,1] }
  #=> ["1.9.2-some-text", "2.0.2-some-text", "2.11.0"]
```

You said, "in above examples output should be `1.9.2-some-text, 2.0.2-some-text, 2.11.0`".  That's neither a string nor an array, so I assumed you wanted an array. If you want a string, tack `.join(', ')` onto the end.

Regex's are naturally "greedy", so `.*\/` will match all characters up to and including the last `/` in each line. `1` returns the contents of the capture group `(.*)` (capture group 1).

Comment: After I answered, I thought that maybe the example is a single string rather than strings, as the OP writes there is a single string.

Comment: Thanks. For input, I assumed it to be a single string (ref. `lines`); for output, I modified my answer slightly.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `lines`.